# Does it make sense to learn Windows Phone 7 development to learn Windows 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

I want to learn Windows 8 development (specially for smartphones) but can't install Windows 8 release preview right now. And there is more info, tutorials, etc. in the internet about Windows Phone with SDK 7.

I know nothing about Windows development. Is Windows Phone with SDK 7 a good basis for Windows 8? Or will I waste my time and it's better to wait and start directly with Windows 8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes. Whether you choose the XAML/C# route or the HTML/JS route, you're not going to learn much while studying Win Phone 7 development that doesn't apply to Win Phone 8 development and even Win 8 development.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to this article at least, although it doesn't talk mainly about development, there are too much differences and it probably doesn't make sense to learn Windows (phone) 7 as "intro".

http://crave.cnet.co.uk/mobiles/windows-phone-7-was-doomed-by-design-microsoft-admits-50008466/

On the other side, there's this article in Microsoft's site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465136

Which clearly suggests there's a significant common base, since the apps are supposed to be easily portable. Hmm... Will see :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not committed to Silverlight you could just go the HTML5 route for Windows 8 apps.  Then you could start learning HTML5 now without having Windows 8 installed.

Since you know nothing about Windows dev, I'd say learn HTML5, then you can use it on the web, as well as on Windows 8 apps.

There's a great series of self-study exercises on up Microsoft's GenerationApp site - http://bit.ly/30tolaunch .   Free, and pretty good for beginner ramp up.

Comment: HTML and Javascript for Windows 8 Apps is very different from HTML and javascript for the web

Comment: Not so much.  Watch Jon Lam's session from teched 2012.  He builds an html editor using an open source library.  Makes it run on the web.  Then moves the source into a win8 project.  Yes, he's gotta tweak it some but the same basic principles work there.

Comment: (continued - hit enter or something and couldnt edit the one above)...  Given this gentlemen wants to get going now, and doesn't have/cant get win8, HTML5 is a good route for him.  He can use most of his skills in the www, then also use them in win8. Johns stuff was an aha moment for me as most of the demos I'd seen previously were using the win8 templates. Here's a link to the session. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV350 .

Comment: Well I actually want to start with c++, since I want to learn it for a while already and this would be a good opportunity to do it (or in worst case c#). But I don't know how this answer the question of Windows phone 7 knowledge being useful for Windows 8?

Comment: Although, in that page about Windows 8 there's a start guide for Android developers and it links to a Windows phone 7 guide. So, unless it's an error, there must be a good common base.

Comment: On the other side I don't understand why "Build for Windows 8" and "Build for Windows Phone" are separate items. The page probably not up to date?

Comment: I'm totally impressed with the c++ and xaml solution in windows 8.  Awesomely productive, and fast.  Won't really help with the 'start with winphone' thing.  Wait for winphone 8?